# Coffeescript wait for multiple api calls to be over

Tags: rest, coffeescript, synchronous, hubot

i am writing a coffeescript, where i am calling around 1000 http URL 's, parsing each and every data from each call and creating an array of result objects. Finally i need to access the array of objects and sort them.

Whats happening is, the code is not waiting for each and every call to be over and instead goes to end of the code where i am sorting the result array. Since the api calls are not over, the resulting array is null and hence getting an exception. I am pasting my code below. Please help me here

```
    topChannels = []
    calcMsgCount = (value) ->
     channelhistoryURL = 'https://some-url'
     msg.http(channelhistoryURL)
     .header('Accept', 'application/json')
     .get() (err, res, body) ->
        if res.statusCode is 200
            try
                data = JSON.parse body
                Channel =
                id: data.id
                name: data.name
                messagecount: data.messages.length
                topChannels.push(Channel)   
                value++
                if (value < response.channels.length)
                    setTimeout calcMsgCount(value),1000
            catch err
                msg.send "JSON parsing error"
                msg.send value
                msg.send err

        else
            msg.send "error while retrieving channel history"
    index=0;
    calcMsgCount(index);
    # Sorting topChannels array based on total number of messages 
    sortByMsgCount = (array, key) ->
       array.sort((a,b) -> b[key] - a[key])
    sortByMsgCount(topChannels, 'messagecount')
```

Comment: Does `msg.http().get()` returns a promise? If so you can use `jquery.when` to wait on all these calls to complete (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Comment: You should use a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) in order to iterate over each calls.

Comment: Not to mention calling 1000's of urls? That seems fishy...

Comment: i cannot use jquery, as this coffee script is a hubot. Also, i cannot get the documentation for msg.http().get().